# React custom input passing props to parent functional component while using custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am new to react and i have a custom input where am handling the value and input handler via a custom hook but would like to get the value and the input handler to the parent component using the custom input but am stuck on how to achieve this.
I have written the following code.

On the custom hook

```
import {useReducer} from "react";

const INITAL_STATE  = {value:'',valid:false,pristine:true,  error:''}
const REDUCER_ACTIONS = { input:"INPUT", blur:"BLUR"}

const reducer = (state,action)=>{
 
  if (action.type === REDUCER_ACTIONS.input){
    return {...state, value: action.value}
  }
  
  if (action.type === REDUCER_ACTIONS.blur){
     return {...state, pristine: false}
   }
 
  return INITAL_STATE;
 }

const useForm = () => {
   const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,INITAL_STATE)

   const onBlurHandler = (event) => {
     dispatch({type:REDUCER_ACTIONS.blur});
   }

 const onInputHandler = (event) => {
     dispatch({type:REDUCER_ACTIONS.input,value:event.target.value})
 }

return {
    ...inputState,
    onBlurHandler,
    onInputHandler
 }
};
export default useForm;
```

And for my custom input i have

```
import useForm from "../../hooks/use-form";
const CustomInput = (props) => {
   const {value, onInputHandler, onBlurHandler} = useForm(); //uses custom hook

    return  <>
         <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
         <input value={value} onBlur={onBlurHandler} onInput={onInputHandler} 
   {...props} />
        </>
}
export default CustomInput;
```

The above custom input  has the onInput and onBlur pointing to the custom hooks since i want to reuse the functionality on other input types like select and date pickers without having to duplicate them.

On my parent component am simply calling the Custom input like

```
 function App() {

    
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <CustomInput onInputHandler={} label="First name"/>
      </div>
   );
  }

export default App;
```

I would like to pass the onInputHandler and value as a props back to the parent component from the custom input but am stuck on how to do this. How do i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you need to pass value, I guess you wanted to pass the initial value of the input to CustomInput. To achieve that you can pass another prop.

1. App.js pass `initialValue` to `CustomInput`

```
<CustomInput
    initialValue={"abc"}
    label="First name"
/>
```

2. In `CustomInput` pass `initialValue` prop to `useForm` hook as an argument.

```
const { value, onInputHandler, onBlurHandler } = useForm(props.initialValue);
```

3. Set the `initialValue` as the `value` in initial state in `useForm`.

```
const useForm = (initialValue) => {
  const [inputState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    ...INITAL_STATE,
    value: initialValue
  });
  ...
  ...
}
```

To pass the `onInputHandler` as a prop you can check if `onInputHandler` is available as a prop and call it along with `onInputHandler` coming from `useForm`.

1. In App.js defines another function that accepts `event` as an argument.

```
export default function App() {
  const onInputHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomInput
        ...
        onInputHandler={onInputHandler}
        label="First name"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

2. In `CustomInput` change the onInput handler like below. You can change the logic as per your needs (I called onInputHandler in `useForm` and `prop`).

```
      <input
        value={value}
        onBlur={onBlurHandler}
        onInput={(e) => {
          props.onInputHandler && props.onInputHandler(e);
          onInputHandler(e);
        }}
        {...props}
      />
```

[image: Edit festive-architecture-dr64t]

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this will be to simply call the `onInputHandler()` from `hooks` and `onInputHandler()` from the `props` received from Parent and send the `e.target.value` as a prop to these functions.

```
    const CustomInput = (props) => {
      const { value, onInputHandler, onBlurHandler } = useForm(); //uses custom hook

      console.log(value);

      const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
        onInputHandler(e);
        props.onInputHandler(e.target.value);
      };

      return (
        <>
          <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
          <input
            value={value}
            onBlur={onBlurHandler}
            onInput={(e) => {
              handleInputChange(e);
            }}
            {...props}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
    export default CustomInput;
```

And in the parent component we can receive them as `props` returned from that function and use it according to our requirement.

```
    function App() {
      
        return (
          <div className="container">
          <CustomInput
            label="name"
            onInputHandler={(value: string) => console.log("App",value)}
          />
          </div>
       );
      }
    
    export default App;
```

sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-lamport-2czb8?file=/src/App.tsx:228-339